# How to select checkbox which is present on any alert?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a button when clicked, a prompt alert will pop up. Using send keys I have entered text in the text area but there is a checkbox which I need to select too which says 'Don't show this message again'.

I cannot do inspect element on alert or any other actions.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the popup or the HTML code?

Comment: Please share the complete details along with the html.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

1) Open dev tool in chrome ->

```
 Press F12
```

2) Now press ->

```
CTRL + SHIFT + C
```

This will enable your cursor to select any element on page.
Click just on the checkbox and see the devtool select/show the exact element on DOM